# Android: Using Paypal SDK Add to cart can be implemented

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to paypal integration with android using paypal SDK .

I just checked code in [PayPal-Android-SDK (GitHub)](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK). Here only buy now button is implemented . I just want to know whether can we make add to cart button instead of buy now button by editing this code .

Comment: @Ankit Lamba Thank you for helping me to understand people very clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jeff from PayPal here.  Unfortunately, the SDK can only be used for one-time checkout, and future payment authentication.  The 'cart' functionality that you desire is not currently available.  You can, however, use the newly added multi-item support to list your items individually to the server, so a user view each item when browsing their previous transactions.

Feel free to submit feature requests in our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/)!  Thanks!

Comment: how to add android framework alpha where u got that jar file can u please help

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Please follow the Readme instructions, and post a new question is anything is unclear.  Thanks!